# Store a loop statement's result in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, web

Below is my code and it produces a **table** with `3 Columns` and `6 Rows`. I want the produced `HTML` syntax to stored the variable in `PHP`. Is there a way this is possible?

```
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
    
        for ($i=0; $i <= $col_count; $i++) { 
            echo "<tr>\n";
            for ($j=0; $j <= $row_count; $j++) { 
               $p = $data2[$i][$j];
               echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: initialize the html table inside a variable, like you normally do `$table = '<table ...'`, then continually concatenate them inside the loop, `$table .= 'markup here'`, like so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below both way codes it's work proper..!**

```
<?php
//one way
    echo '<table border ="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">';
    for ($i=0; $i <= $col_count; $i++) 
    { 
        echo '<tr>\n';
        for ($j=0; $j <= $row_count; $j++) 
        { 
            $p = $data2[$i][$j];
            echo '<td>'.$p.'</td> \n';
        }
        echo '/tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
//second way(all html tag and string store in one php variable and after echo in last)
    $tbl = '<table border ="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">';
    for ($i=0; $i <= $col_count; $i++) 
    { 
        $tbl .= '<tr>\n';
        for ($j=0; $j <= $row_count; $j++) 
        { 
            $p = $data2[$i][$j];
            $tbl .= '<td>'.$p.'</td> \n';
        }
        $tbl .= '/tr>';
    }
    $tbl .= '</table>';
    echo $tbl;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy solution would be to use [output buffering functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();

// echo your stuff here exactly as you are right now

$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Then you can `echo $html` (or `<?= $html ?>` if you're not in a PHP tag already) wherever / as many times as needed.

This should also be faster than using concatenation over and over again.